# ¿como clonar el branch de un repositorio en github?

Tags: git, github

estoy realizando un proyecto y he clonado un proyecto de github. A este, le he clonado otro dentro, y le he agregado unos scripts dentro.

He hecho un repositorio en github, y he subido mi proyecto, a una ruta que sería
[https://github.com/"miperfil"/"proyecto"/tree/master](https://github.com/%22miperfil%22/%22proyecto%22/tree/master)

es decir, es un branch si no me equivoco.

Simplemente lo quiero para clonarlo desde una maquina ubuntu de 0, pero cuando lo clono, aparece solamente el readme.txt , que es lo único que sale cuando entras al repositorio.

Mi pregunta es,¿ cómo puedo pasar el branch a la raiz del repositorio directamente, o como puedo descargar el branch desde esta nueva maquina ubuntu?

Un saludo y muchas gracias

Comment: ¿ves en github que efectivamente se ha subido todo el proyecto?
hiciste un : git pus origin master o git push origin main?

Comment: Creo que no le has hecho push

Comment: ya lo tengo, como puedo hacer que para clonarlo, aunque sea privado, pida permiso al autor y no le pida sus credenciales?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya he encontrado la respuesta por si alguien mas tiene el mismo error, es ejecutar este comando

```
git clone --single-branch --branch <branchname> <remote-repo>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando lo clones puede ser que no veas nada por que actualmente estes situado en el master, pero puedes moverte entre sus ramas

```
git checkout 'la rama buscada'
```